# archiving data row from a table to another

Tags: php, mysql, archive

would like to archive a patient by moving the record from one table to another. This is the code I am trying to use:

```js
<?php

$patient_id = $_GET['patient_id'];
include("db.php");

$sql="Select * from patient where patient_id=".$patient_id;
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//Call the function to archive the table
//Function definition is given below
archive_record(patient,$row);

//Once you archive, delete the record from original table

$sql = "Delete from patient where patient_id=".$patient_id;
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


function archive_record($patient_archive,$row)
{
 $sql = "insert into patient_archive values(";
 $i=0;
 while($i<(count($row)-1))
 {
  $sql.="'".$row[$i]."',";
 }
 $i=$i+1;
 
 $sql.="'".$row[$i]."'";
 $sql.=")";

 
}
?>
```

i get this result after i run the code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt6s6.png)

how can i improve this code to get my desired result?

**error after debugging**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfgaV.png)

Comment: first correct this: `archive_record(patient,$row);` - what shall 'patient' be? `$patient_archive` isn't used in function `archive_record()`

Comment: second: `$i=$i+1;` is outside the while, so the while will run forever, which is your second error.

Comment: third: you never execute the `$sql` created in `archive_records`.

Comment: forth: your code is highly insecure, open to sql injections. Switch to prepared statements or at the ver least sanitise the user input (`$_GET['patient_id']`).

Comment: i apply your suggestions and it leads me to a lot of error. see in my lower post for the snip of it

Comment: Please, add errors as text to the question, not as an image

Comment: first and last error are self-explanatory. The "undefined offset" is because [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns a numeric _and_ associative keys by default in the array. simply use [msqli_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) to only get the numeric ones.

Comment: it does not shows error now but the data just stays and does not archive and deleted

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to **copy** the row:

```
function archive_record($patient_id)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO patient_archive (field1, field1, ...) SELECT t.field1, t.field1, .... FROM patient t WHERE t.patient_id = '$patient_id'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    //Ten you can write your delete query here  
}
```